# Macbook Air M1 won't run Blazor Application with normal build, but runs with "dotnet run" command

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Just picked up the new Macbook Air M1 and wanted to do some Blazor development on it, but I've encountered my first issue. The application won't run with when I build it, no automatic browser pop-up. The only way I can make the application run is by going to the Terminal inside Visual Studio and type "dotnet run", and then manually copy https://localhost:5001/ into the browser. I have installed .NET 5.0, and I've also tried with .NET Core 3.1.

Here it is with normal build, just stuck at "Loaded 'usr......' "
[image: Normal build]

If I use dotnet run, it runs...
[image: Normal build]

Answer (score 1):

.NET does not yet fully support Apple Silicon: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43313

All you can do for now is grin-and-bear-it.

Comment: That sucks... Do you know when support will be added? I can live with 1-2 months.

Comment: @icantprogram Run a Windows VM, or if you need a macOS environment you could use a service like MacInCloud.com or MacStadium.

Comment: @Dai, Parallels does not work on M1 yet, it is still in development.

Comment: @JeffLongo QEMU works: https://www.slashgear.com/apple-m1-mac-running-windows-10-arm-is-embarrassing-for-surface-pro-x-29649132/

Comment: @Dai, that is awesome, will check it out immediately!